# How can I get back the original code from this enumerator decompilation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I am trying to decompile some code from an old unity project for which only the build is available (after an accident involving data loss). Most of the code is decompiled relatively well, but enumerators provide code like this:

```
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <LoadFileTables>c__Iterator8 : IDisposable, IEnumerator, IEnumerator<object>
    {
        internal object $current;
        internal int $PC;
        internal DesignFileTableLoader<> f__this;
    internal IEnumerator<iter> __1;
    internal TableLoaderWorker<worker> __0;

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.$PC = -1;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        uint num = (uint)this.$PC;
        this.$PC = -1;
        switch (num)
        {
            case 0:
                this.< worker > __0 = new TableLoaderWorker(this.<> f__this.TableReader);
                this.< iter > __1 = this.<> f__this.LoadTable(this.< worker > __0, this.<> f__this._file.ElementTable, this.<> f__this.ElementTableStrategy);
                break;

            case 1:
                break;

            case 2:
                goto Label_00EB;

            case 3:
                goto Label_0145;

            case 4:
                goto Label_019F;

            case 5:
                goto Label_01F9;

            default:
                goto Label_0210;
        }
        if (this.< iter > __1.MoveNext())
        {
            this.$current = null;
            this.$PC = 1;
            goto Label_0212;
        }
        this.< iter > __1 = this.<> f__this.LoadTable(this.< worker > __0, this.<> f__this._file.LayerTable, this.<> f__this.LayerTableStrategy);
    Label_00EB:
        while (this.< iter > __1.MoveNext())
        {
            this.$current = null;
            this.$PC = 2;
            goto Label_0212;
        }
        this.< iter > __1 = this.<> f__this.LoadTable(this.< worker > __0, this.<> f__this._file.SceneTable, this.<> f__this.SceneTableStrategy);
    Label_0145:
        while (this.< iter > __1.MoveNext())
        {
            this.$current = null;
            this.$PC = 3;
            goto Label_0212;
        }
        this.< iter > __1 = this.<> f__this.LoadTable(this.< worker > __0, this.<> f__this._file.MaterialTable, this.<> f__this.MaterialTableStrategy);
    Label_019F:
        while (this.< iter > __1.MoveNext())
        {
            this.$current = null;
            this.$PC = 4;
            goto Label_0212;
        }
        this.< iter > __1 = this.<> f__this.LoadTable(this.< worker > __0, this.<> f__this._file.StatisticsTable, this.<> f__this.StatisticsTableStrategy);
    Label_01F9:
        while (this.< iter > __1.MoveNext())
        {
            this.$current = null;
            this.$PC = 5;
            goto Label_0212;
        }
        this.$PC = -1;
    Label_0210:
        return false;
    Label_0212:
        return true;
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public void Reset()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    object IEnumerator<object>.Current =>
        this.$current;

        object IEnumerator.Current =>
            this.$current;
    }

[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <LoadTable>c__Iterator9 : IDisposable, IEnumerator, IEnumerator<object>
    {
        internal object $current;
        internal int $PC;
        internal ITableLoadStrategy<$> strategy;
internal IDesignFileTable<$> table;
internal TableLoaderWorker<$> worker;
internal Exception<exception> __0;
internal ITableLoadStrategy strategy;
internal IDesignFileTable table;
internal TableLoaderWorker worker;

[DebuggerHidden]
public void Dispose()
{
    this.$PC = -1;
}

public bool MoveNext()
{
    uint num = (uint)this.$PC;
    this.$PC = -1;
    switch (num)
    {
        case 0:
            this.worker.StartLoadingTable(this.table, this.strategy);
            break;

        case 1:
            break;

        default:
            return false;

    }
    if (!this.worker.IsFinished)
    {
        this.$current = null;
        this.$PC = 1;
        return true;
    }
    this.< exception > __0 = this.worker.BackgroundThreadException;
    if (this.< exception > __0 != null)
    {
        throw this.< exception > __0;
    }
    this.$PC = -1;        
}

[DebuggerHidden]
public void Reset()
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}

object IEnumerator<object>.Current =>
    this.$current;

        object IEnumerator.Current =>
            this.$current;
    }
}
```

I don't really understand how it works or how to rewrite it, what's going on with those dollared variables and gotos?

Comment: Do you have symbols (.pdb) left after that accident?

Comment: @Evk doesn't seem so, unity apparently won't include them in builds. There is a .mdb file however, if it's of any help.

Comment: Well mdb is the same as pdb, but for mono. Unfortunately I don't know any decompiler that can work with mdb, nor do I know any way to convert mdb to pdb. So it seems you are stuck with manually dechipering this mess